# In a javascript class, how to have a method inherit from another method?

Tags: javascript, function, class, methods, static

In my Javascript class Order, I have a static method and a non-static method, and they both contain the same code. If possible, how would one of these methods inherit the code from the other? This is an attempt to make my code look more readable since it's becoming quite unwieldy.

Comment: Move the method out of the class and use asa utility. Is easier to test. This is the reason for using functional programming over oo programing. Oo has more benefit for a specific purpose. Describing and object and giving it methods. Ungortunately this oo approach seems to be applied to everything and adds unnecessary complication.

Comment: you could call the static method inside the no static method. with this you will not have to use same code in both places

Answer (score 0):

You can use classes and inheritance, create a parent class and then a subclass. The extends keyword makes the methods of the parent class available inside the child class.
The super keyword calls the constructor of the parent class.

```js
//Parent class (superclass)
class Animal {                            
  constructor(name) {           
    this._name = name;
  }
  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }
} 

//Child class (subclass)
class Cat extends Animal {             
  constructor(name, usesLitter) {
    super(name);                    
    this._usesLitter = usesLitter;
  }
    get usesLitter() {
    return this._usesLitter;
  }
}
const bryceCat = new Cat('Bryce', true);
console.log(bryceCat.name);             //Output: Bryce
console.log(bryceCat.usesLitter);       //Output: true
```

To create a static method you can use the static keyword. For example, generateName() you can call it directly from the class, but not from an instance of the class.

```js
class Human {
  constructor(name) {
    this._name = name;
  
  static generateName() {       
    const names = ['Angel', 'Pedro', 'Luis', 'Mario', 'Julio'];
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
    return names[randomNumber];
  }
} 
console.log(Human.generateName());  // Returns a random name.
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort in your answer, but I am talking about a single class with methods that inherit code from another method in that same class. Your example involves using multiple classes for the inheritance.